# Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed Unreal Engine 4.26

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I try to implement the pawn navigation to the player in my game. When I tried that in BP site, it worked perfectly, but I try to transform that in C++ code. And I got a kind of wird error. Befor this I faced another error but I find the NavigationSystem was changed a bit in my ue version, but I figured out problem by changing to UNavigationSystemV1. It might be interfering with my class?

NavPath pointer it gave me the error.

Here is the error list:

```
> Error (active)    E0393   pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed 37
> Error (active)    E0393   pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed 40
> Error C2027   use of undefined type 'UNavigationPath'37
> Error C2027   use of undefined type 'UNavigationPath' 40
```

Here is the part of problematic code:

```
FVector ASTrackerBot::GetNextPathPoint()
{
ACharacter* PlayerPawn =  UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerCharacter(this, 0);

UNavigationPath* NavPath = UNavigationSystemV1::FindPathToActorSynchronously(this, 
GetActorLocation(), PlayerPawn);

if (NavPath->PathPoints.Num() > 1)
{

    return NavPath->PathPoints[1];
}


return GetActorLocation();
```

}

Here is my entire private cpp file:

```
#include "AI/STrackerBot.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "Kismet/GameplayStatics.h"
#include "Runtime\NavigationSystem\Public\NavigationSystem.h"
#include "Runtime/Engine/Classes/Components/InputComponent.h"


// Sets default values
ASTrackerBot::ASTrackerBot()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    MeshComp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("MeshComp"));
    MeshComp->SetCanEverAffectNavigation(false);
    RootComponent = MeshComp;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void ASTrackerBot::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    
}

FVector ASTrackerBot::GetNextPathPoint()
{
    // parcurgere drum pana la locatia playerului
    ACharacter* PlayerPawn =  UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerCharacter(this, 0);
    
    UNavigationPath* NavPath = UNavigationSystemV1::FindPathToActorSynchronously(this, GetActorLocation(), PlayerPawn);

    if (NavPath->PathPoints.Num() > 1)
    {
        // Return next point in the path
        return NavPath->PathPoints[1];
    }

    // nu a reusti sa gaseasca drumul
    return GetActorLocation();
}

// Called every frame
void ASTrackerBot::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}
```

And here is my header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Pawn.h"
#include "STrackerBot.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class GAME_API ASTrackerBot : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    ASTrackerBot();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category = "Components")
    UStaticMeshComponent* MeshComp;

    FVector GetNextPathPoint();

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

};
```

Comment: Please post the error in full.

Comment: I added the full error list :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also need to add the `NavigationSystem` module to your Project.Build.cs file in the `PublicDependencyModuleNames` array.

Comment: Thanks that worked bypassing the LNK2019.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `UNavigationPath` needs to be available at the point where you do `NavPath->PathPoints`. Without the definition, how does the compiler know that `UNavigationPath` even has a member called `PathPoints`? You can *have* a pointer to a declared but undefined class (i.e., one you defined like `class UNavigationPath;` with no body) and pass it around but you can't access any of its members. Find the header file that defines `UNavigationPath` and make sure it's included in your source.

Comment: In UE 4.20 and above the UNavigationPath it's included in NavigationSystem.h, which I included. #include "Runtime/NavigationSystem/Public/NavigationSystem.h"

Comment: Curiously that `#include` line in your source uses backslashes instead of forward slashes. Does that work on your system?

Comment: First time it was generated automatically like that, and then I changed to forward slashes style, it seems to work in both ways.

Comment: @RobertMaximus try to directly include the relevant header:  /Engine/Source/Runtime/NavigationSystem/Public/NavigationPath.h

Comment: I think something is wonky with your includes or the include path. You're doing `#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"` and then later you include `InputComponent.h` with a different path even though these headers are in the same directory. Are you sure your build isn't emitting warnings about not being able to find header files, or maybe including the same header through different paths?

Comment: @WillisBlackburn no warnings, it's only those errors

Comment: What's the command you're using to compile?

Comment: @RobertMaximus, what do you mean by that? Does it produce the same compile error with that approach?

Comment: @Secundi with that approach it gave me the LNK2019 error, which is not an actually a code error, but it's not working like that.

Comment: @RobertMaximus I suggest that you compile your file with the option that dumps out the preprocessor output, which if you're using Visual C++ is probably `/E` (with line numbers) or `/EP` (without). It will expand all the `#include` files and `#define` macros and enable you to see exactly what the compiler is getting as input. Load up the preprocessed file (it will be huge) and see if there's a definition for `UNavigationPath` somewhere. If you upload that file somewhere and post a link, I'll take a look at it.