# C++ pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed on UTextureRenderTarget2D Unreal Engine 5 EA

Tags: c++, shader, screenshot, unreal-engine5

I am trying to take a Scene capture of an Unreal Project 5 Scene and send its pixel content to a compute shader to do some transformations on the rendered image. The goal of that shader would be to send a standard resolution and a high resolution image to the shader.

After some research, I came across `USceneCaptureComponent2D` that could be used to generate a `Texture2D` element that could be used to extract the pixel data from the image (https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/dwu3sf/get_output_in_pixels_from_camera/)

However, it appears that I cannot manipulate the Render Target since it has an `incomplete` type:
[image: error]

Right now, on the TickComponent method, I am getting the user's camera and setting the scene capture camera view to the latest POV of the player's camera:

```cpp
void UComputeShaderTestComponent::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    if (UWorld* World = GetWorld())
    {
        APlayerCameraManager* PlayerCameraManager = World->GetFirstPlayerController()->PlayerCameraManager;
        SceneCapture->SetCameraView(PlayerCameraManager->GetLastFrameCameraCachePOV());
    }
}
```

I was wondering if those changes were coming from UE5 and if so, is there a better way I can send all the pixels displayed on the screen to a shader?

Source code of the model I am using: https://github.com/mortmaire/Unreal-Engine-Access-Render-Target

Modules I am using in the `Build.cs` file:

```cs
PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[] {
            "Core",
            "CoreUObject",
            "Engine",
            "InputCore",
            "RenderCore",
            "RHI"
        });
```

The following post suggests it could be caused by a missing module in the above list. I tried adding Renderer and it did not work.
[Pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed Unreal Engine 4.26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66295943/pointer-to-incomplete-class-type-is-not-allowed-unreal-engine-4-26)

Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to include the header [`Engine/TextureRenderTarget2D.h`](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/UTextureRenderTarget2D/).

Comment: seems like it did it! Thanks ^^' Thought that the include that allowed me to use the type would do it all